# PDF randomly does not show parts of the text without errors in compilation

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am writing my thesis with `pdflatex` and did not have any problems until now. When I compile my thesis I don't get any errors. However a part of a sentence is suddenly missing (so that a part of a line is just blank). I was trying to locate what the reason for this is, and it seems to be that if I remove one or two words in the last sentence of the paragraph (or somewhere else), the text looks fine. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? All references are fine and everything compiled just fine yesterday. Today I added some minor corrections from my professor and this suddenly happened.

If I compile the same paragraph separately with the same preamble, I don't get this problem.

I attached two images, to illustrate the problem:

Compiling in Document:

[image: Compiling in Document]

Compiling Separately:

[image]

If a MWE example helps, I can do that, but obviously everything works, the text is just radomly missing...

Here is a more or less minimal working example:

```
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\documentclass[a4paper,
final,
12pt,
numbers=noendperiod, 
BCOR=5.00mm,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}




\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

% Font Encoding 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=.83]{beramono}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{operators}{`=} % redefine math for chemmacros
%\usepackage{eulervm} % Math typing
\usepackage{microtype}



\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{acf.bib}


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% mehrere Spalten vereinigen
\usepackage{multirow}

% Better table layouts
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}

% Paket für Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}



\usepackage{tabularx}



\frenchspacing


% Mathematische Sachen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xspace}




%%\usepackage{overpic}
\newcommand{\pnmr}{\textsuperscript{31}P-NMR\xspace}
\newcommand{\phnmr}{\textsuperscript{31}P\{\textsuperscript{1}H\}-NMR\xspace}
\newcommand{\hnmr}{\textsuperscript{1}H-NMR\xspace}
\newcommand{\cnmr}{\textsuperscript{13}C-NMR\xspace}
\newcommand{\cnmrh}{\textsuperscript{13}C\{\textsuperscript{1}H\}-NMR\xspace}
\newcommand{\engl}{\textit{engl.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\via}{\textit{via}\xspace}


\newcommand{\M}{[M]\textsuperscript{+}}
\newcommand{\MH}{[M+H]\textsuperscript{+}}

\newcommand{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\textrm{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}

\usepackage[within=chapter]{newfloat}


\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=los,
name=Scheme,
listname={List of Schemes},
]{scheme}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,
font=onehalfspacing,font=footnotesize}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=2ex}


\captionsetup[sub]{font+=footnotesize}


\usepackage{multicol}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}


\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} % Use EPS graphics with pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\cmpdsetup{cmpd-style =\rmfamily, ref-style = \rmfamily}
\usepackage{chemgreek}




\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% Automatic List of Abbreviations % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand*{\nomprefix}{}
\newcommand*{\nom}[2]{#1\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
% % latex run, then use nomencl command, then run latex again

% % % % % % % %Header % %
\pagestyle{headings}
%\setcapindent{1.5em}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%Hyperref % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

%\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,hyperfootnotes=false,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
            citecolor=DarkGreen,
            linkcolor=black, %DarkBlue,
            urlcolor=black} % % Bestimme Farben von Hyperrefverweisen

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\begin{document}

The structures of these PN ring systems have been extensively studied in the solid state
\via single crystal X\mbox{-}ray crystallography, where in a predominant number of cases
only the thermodynamically favoured \textit{cis} isomers can be observed. 

\pnmr experiments on the other hand suggest that both \textit{cis} and \textit{trans}
species can be encountered in nearly equal amounts in solution.\supercite{Stahl2000}

Although there is a general consensus in the literature that the \textit{cis} isomer is 
the more stable product, little is known about the reasons for this trend.

Low\mbox{-}level \textit{ab\mbox{ }initio} and semi\mbox{-}empirical calculations 
presented by Haiduc and co-workers in 1994 provide insight into the source of puckering,     
but fail to explain observed stabilities.\supercite{Silaghi-Dumitrescu1994}

Another related facet of cyclodiphosphazane chemistry that has received little attention
is the mechanism of ring inversion, where vertex inversion at the phosphorus, edge   
inversion at the imino nitrogen and a sequence of cycloreversion and cycloaddition have     
been proposed.\supercite{Chen1985,Wirringa1995,Silaghi-Dumitrescu1998,Schranz1999} %,  

     \end{document}
```

Comment: What is the result, if the file is viewed in a different PDF viewer?

Comment: The result is the same. The text is just missing.

Comment: Then create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)  or post at least the relevant source code.

Comment: I can do that. The problem is that if I remove the text out of the context, this problem does not appear. But I will add the MWE of course.

Comment: ... which could also be an indicator that possibly something is not as it should long before the compiler reaches that location. I've seen similarly mysterious things happen out of presumably valid sources which compiled without the slightest warning, but there was a missing bracket or erroneous equation/math or what not long before the location at which problems visually occured in the output document.

Comment: What can I do in this case?

Comment: Please take your first example (with the error), than delete all the text after that. Check if the error persist. Than delete half of the text before the error. If the error is still there, do it again, and so on. Like this, you can reduce the code. If you are done, minimize the number of packages the same way.

Comment: Ok, found it. Apparently it is this expression:

 `[\{R'NHP(\chemmu-NR)\}\ce{_2}]`

But what is wrong with it? It is one of the things I added today, so that does make sense in some way.

Comment: @Vlad030691: Please add that line to the MWE, and the appropriate packages, and see if that reproduces the problem.

Comment: No it does not reproduce it. It only works in the whole document.

Comment: Are you running pdflatex in nonstop mode?

Comment: Ok sorry I was wrong, I have now added the paragraph to my document and it looks fine again (?) I have literally no idea what happened.

Comment: I run latex in the following way:

pdflatex.exe -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Comment: What happens if you try it without `-interaction=nonstopmode`?

Comment: @IanThompson: This does not change anything. Ok, apparently the problem just disappeared after I entered some other corrections (normal text)?

Comment: The behaviour of `TeX` can be quite unpredictable if it tries to plough through errors, so I thought this might be the problem. If you don't have any errors elsewhere in the document, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: As I said before, the problems seems to be resolved now and I have no idea what happened. Thank you all for your help and effort! If I find the reason, I will definitely describe it here.

Comment: Nice to read that you were able to solve it. As it's a bit unclear (and solved) I closed the question. You can still comment or vote to reopen if you would like to write an answer.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I think it is a bug. I got exactly the same error. In my case, it appears to be an interaction between text spacing and footnote spacing, despite the footnote being nowhere near the text that disappears. I cannot produce an WME in my case, but what happens in common is that only the first word of the line shows up, and attempting to select the rest of the line suggests that it has run off to the right far beyond the page margin.

Comment: I'm currently using MiKTeX 2.9.5700 on Win7. My document is 2-column and totally different in layout from the one here. I am sure it is partly due to hyperref or cleveref or footnotes or some combination of them, because the text appears before the references are updated, after which it disappears despite no actual text changing. I know this by changing a label name.

Comment: Worse still, I found the following. There are 3 versions of the document A,B,C such that when I change+compile in the following sequence A -> B -> C -> B -> A, the text does not appear for the first B but appears for the second B. This can be repeated cyclically and the text does not appear for every A and every B that follows an A. @HeikoOberdiek: Do you have any idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: I found a transition A -> B where the change causes 3 passes. On the first pass, the text shows correctly, while the internal references are "??". On the second pass, the text remains, and the internal references show correctly, but the bibliographic references are "?". On the third pass, the text disappears at exactly the same time that the bibliographic references are updated correctly. This strongly suggests it is hyperref that is buggy. Does that help?

Comment: The "MWE" is much too large. It loads tons of packages. The very most of them are very likely not relevant for the problem. Please, minimize the preamble (the problem should still present of course).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I'm not the asker, but got the same problem. In my case even the slightest change makes the bug vanish so I couldn't get an MWE. For example, deleting plain text many pages later (not affecting the layout of the pages up to the disappearing text) causes the problem to vanish! Anyway, the packages we have in common are only hyperref, amsmath, xcolor, graphicx, caption, and I strongly believe it is hyperref.

Comment: @user21820 The example does not use graphics, tables,  but loads `graphicx`, `longtable`, `dcolumn`, `multirow`, ... Removing packages that are not used and that are not relevant for the problem is a trivial task.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Okay, but as I said I'm not the asker. Right now I don't have the time to wade through someone else's version of the problem, so if nobody has a quick answer/fix then it's okay.